# Pip refuses to install inside Anaconda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to install some packages inside my freshly created virtual environment that I created with Anaconda.

Creating a fresh environment:

```
kali@kali: conda create --name py2 python=2.7
```

Activating the environment (py2) is now added at the start of the prompt

```
kali@kali: conda activate py2
```

Making sure pip is installed inside the environment:

```
(py2) kali@kali: conda install pip
```

I checked if the installation was successfully installed inside the environment:

```
(py2) kali@kali: cd ~/anaconda3/envs/py2/bin
```

I also performed a 'which' command on the pip installation:

```
(py2) kali@kali: which ~/anaconda3/envs/py2/bin/pip 
Result:
/home/kali/anaconda3/envs/py2/bin/pip
```

When calling the pip installation directly inside the folder:

```
(py2) kali@kali: ~/anaconda3/envs/py2/bin/pip --version  
Result:
pip 20.2.4 from /home/kali/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

However, when I try to install a module it keeps pointing outside the environment:

```
(py2) kali@kali: /home/kali/anaconda3/envs/py2/bin/pip install pycrypto
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto in /home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.6.1)
```

Comment: Have you activated your `conda` environment when using `/home/kali/anaconda3/envs/py2/bin/pip install pycrypto`

Comment: Yes, check step 2 in the original post.

Comment: But the environment name should be in brackets at the start of the prompt if activated.

Comment: Yes I know, it is in there. But still, even without activating it, a direct install from within the path should work as well

Comment: But its not shown in the examples.

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal Added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223544/discussion-between-abhigyan-jaiswal-and-awa).

Comment: You shouldn't be using pip with Anaconda installed.  Whereever you use pip use conda instread.

Comment: Have you tried running just `pip install pycrypto` when the environment is activated?

Comment: Yes, also not working